# javaScript got stuck with converting bytes

Tags: javascript

so I've got a bit of the problem. I am trying to make a function in wich : human clicks on input box with mouse and types some random numbers in bytes and that number should be convert and shown in two other boxes such as MegaBytes and KiloBytes. So my problem is that Javascript shows me error :

> Cannot set property 'value' of null
>       at convert (script.js:7)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onkeyup

here is my code so far:

```
function convert(inputas)
{
    var i;
    if(inputas == "B")
    {
        i = document.getElementById("baitas").value / 1000;
        document.getElementById("kiloBaitas").value = i;
    }
    else if(inputas == "KB")
    {
        i = document.getElementById("kiloBaitas").value * 1024;
        document.getElementById("baitas").value = i.toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="baitas" onkeyup="convert('B')placeholder="Bits">
<input type="text" id="kilobaitas"     
`onkeyup="convert('KB')"placeholder="Kilobits">
 <input type="text" id="megabaitas" onkeyup="convert('MB')" 
placeholder="Mbits">
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Where's your html code?

Comment: When this script runs, there is no element present in the document with ID `kiloBaitas` or `baitas` (depending on the `inputas` value)

Comment: @Kinduser  I added my html code above , maybe this will help

Comment: Why do you want to reinvent ...There is a library for the same fileSize.js https://filesizejs.com/

Comment: kilobaitis case sensitive issue.

Comment: @Geeky is it  jquery library ? because I whant to do it in pure javaScript

Comment: It is vanila javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196)

Comment: @FelixKling , thank you for info , mate ;) will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when comparing your javascript with the html. the kilobaitis element is not spelt with a consistent case.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is **case sensitive**.

```js
function convert(inputas) {
  var i;
  if (inputas == "B") {
    i = document.getElementById("baitas").value / 1000;
    document.getElementById("kilobaitas").value = i;
  } else if (inputas == "KB") {
    i = document.getElementById("kiloBaitas").value * 1024;
    document.getElementById("baitas").value = i.toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="baitas" onkeyup="convert('B')" placeholder=" Bits ">
<input type="text " id="kilobaitas" onkeyup="convert('KB')" placeholder="Kilobits ">
<input type="text " id="megabaitas" onkeyup="convert('MB')" placeholder="Mbits ">
```

Comment: yeah , mate just seen it , after long 12h , I am such a sleeping beauty , that I didnt noticed my spelling was incorrect, thank you , mate :)

Comment: cha.. you too , buddy ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {

var elems = [],
    elemsId = ['baitas','kilobaitas','megabaitas'];

function fix(a){ return ( a * 100 | 0 ) / 100  }

function convert(inputas)
{
    var i;
    switch(inputas)
    {
        case 0:
            i = elems[0].value;
            elems[1].value = fix( i / 1024 );
            elems[2].value = fix( i / 1048576 );
            break;
        case 1:
            i = elems[1].value;
            elems[0].value = i * 1024;
            elems[2].value = fix( i / 1024 );
            break;
        case 2:
            i = elems[2].value;
            elems[0].value = i * 1048576;
            elems[1].value = i * 1024;
            break;
    }
}

for (var i=0; i < elemsId.length; i++)
{
    elems[i] = document.getElementById( elemsId[i] );
    elems[i].addEventListener('keyup', convert.bind(null, i) )
}

}());
```

```html
<input type="text" id="baitas" placeholder=" Bits">
<input type="text" id="kilobaitas" placeholder=" Kilobits">
<input type="text" id="megabaitas" placeholder=" Mbits">
```